# Java Server Socket - Only works locally (TCP)

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, client

I have a server/client application written in java.  Basically when  the client tries to connect to the server locally (127.0.0.1 as IP) everything works fine.  However when I use my personal IP address (home address) I get a connection timeout error.

*I have portforwarded correctly, tested using [port check tool](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)

*I also checked using netstat -a in command prompt

*I am hosting on port 9005

here is some of my client code, where I assume I am doing somthing wrong:

```
    public void run() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
String serverAddress = "xx.xx.xx.xxx"; //My actual IP is here in the program

Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9005);

in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    socket.getInputStream()));
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
String playerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        this,
        "Choose Username:",
        "Name Selection",
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
out.println("NEW "+playerName);
```

I'm fairly new to server programing in Java, any suggestions would be appreciated.
I can post more code if requested, just didn't want to post a mountain of it.
thanks.

EDIT: here is some server code:

```
    private final static int PORT = 9005;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Server s = new Server();
s.setSize(50,100);
s.setDefaultCloseOperation(s.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
s.setVisible(true);
System.out.println("Server running");
ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);

try {
    while (true) {
        new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
    }
```

Comment: can you post your server binding code as well?

Comment: Are you doing this on a LAN or across the Internet?

Comment: This would be for across the internet, locally it works fine.

Comment: There was a question very similar to this yesterday.  Not suggesting this is what you were doing, but they had 192.168.1.2 as their IP address, without realising that it wasn't a "REAL" IP address.  Hang on, I'll see if I can find the question.

Comment: ha, no it is not my 192.168, it is the actual IP

Comment: OK, cool.  I won't bother hunting down the question.  Just worth checking these things first.

Comment: Your Java code looks fine to me.  And the fact that it works on 127.0.0.1 suggests that the Java is actually fine; and it's an actual connectivity issue.  As such, the clever people who can give you an answer might not be the programmers on Stack Overflow.  Maybe Super User or something?  I don't know.

Comment: alright, thanks though.  I'm going to try and download private server code to a game or something and see if I can host that properly.  I suppose that will tell me if it's truly a connection issue.

Comment: Can you ping the server address?

Comment: Yes i can ping the address fine.